# ASP.NET 5 and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been using Visual Studio Community 2015 for a while, but recently I got a minor update for web tools. After updating, I lost the ASP.NET 5 project templates in the ASP.NET Web Application creation dialogue. I went to the get.asp.net and the download was gone. Since then, I've tried repairing Visual Studio, repairing .NET Core, and now I'm onto uninstalling and reinstalling both, but that would take a really long time, so I need to know what I can do to bring ASP.NET 5 back.

Comment: Try re-installing only .net core http://dotnet.github.io/ framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ASP.NET 5" is no more (it's ASP.NET Core now), and the templates have moved around a bit.

After installing the [latest .NET Core tooling](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core) and [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx), there are new ASP.NET Core templates available in the New Project dialog under **.NET Core**:

[image]

Pick **ASP.NET Core Web Application** to create a new ASP.NET project targeting .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net 5 is now listed under .Net Core. The menu option is under Visual C# when you go to add a new project. To create a web app, you would select ASP.NET Core Web Application which is a preview template for ASP.NET 5